# How do I load balance on two different ISP connections using squid?

Tags: squid, load-balancing

I am trying to use two different isp connections to load balance the request. I have tried it with ip route:

> ip route replace default scope global nexthop dev ppp0 weight 1 nexthop dev ppp1 weight 1

But it doesn't work well. Nearly all requests timed out.

I am using squid 2.7. Is there any other possibility to use that?

Comment: Before you even think about the Squid configuration, get the policy routing configured correctly so that both connections work.

Comment: The route command provided would create equal cost routes out of the two connections.  Routing happens at an IP packet level not a TCP session level, so half of the packets in a single http session would go out one interface, and the other out of another interface.  From the recieving side, they would see this as seperate traffic from two different IP addresses.  It would appear entirely broken.

Comment: Which connection a packet takes has to be based on its source address. This will ensure a valid setup. Then you can work on getting Squid to load balance by influencing how it chooses the source addresses it uses for its outbound connections.

Comment: So it would be possible to add routes depending on the src ip or what would you advice?

Comment: I prefer to load balance at the router using one with a dual WAN interface - much simpler to manage.

Comment: Yes but I don't have such a device. I have two UMTS sticks, which are the two WAN connections. So I have to decide with IP or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easiest to tell squid to use http cache from both ISPs and round-robin between these HTTP caches.

But here's some stuff on source routing:
http://linux-ip.net/html/adv-multi-internet.html

Use `iptables -j MARK` to mark the packets based on source address, then create a new routing table in */etc/iproutes/rt_tables* and add a new rule `ip rule add fwmark 4 table 4 priority 10000`.